# No XML response when using cURL

Tags: php, curl, response

Is there a reason why a PHP cURL enblaed server will refuse to display xml responses?  I have been working on a script to post numbers to a dialling service.  I felt using cURL would be the best thing to do.

On 3 different servers, each running different versions of PHP, I am able to get responses with no problems.  But on the particular server, no matter how many times I try, I just get a blank response.

This the script in question:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['request_callback'])
{
$customer_name      = cleaninput($_REQUEST['customer_name'],"text");
$debtor_id          = cleaninput($_REQUEST['debtor_id'],"number");
$telephone_number   = cleaninput($_REQUEST['customer_number'],"number");

$xml_request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml_request .= '<CallRequest>';
$xml_request .= '<ProjectName>Noble Test</ProjectName>';
$xml_request .= '<ContactNumberToDial>'.$telephone_number.'</ContactNumberToDial>';
if (isset($_POST['callme_now'])) {
    $xml_request .= '<DateTimeToDial></DateTimeToDial>';
} else {
    $xml_request .= '<DateTimeToDial>' . date('Y-m-d ' . $_POST['hour_select'] . ':' . $_POST['minute_select'] . ':s') . '</DateTimeToDial>';
}
$xml_request .= '<ListSource>WebLead</ListSource>';
$xml_request .= '<AgentName></AgentName>';
$xml_request .= '<AddToList>False</AddToList>';
$xml_request .= '<SpecificAgent>False</SpecificAgent>';
$xml_request .= '<DBField>';
$xml_request .= '<FieldName>Name</FieldName>';
$xml_request .= '<FieldValue>NobleTesting</FieldValue>';
$xml_request .= '</DBField>';
$xml_request .= '</CallRequest>';

$loginUsername = "username";
$loginPassword = "password";
//$user_agent    = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

// Send using CURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://194.217.1.2/ClickToCall/CallRequest.asmx/Call");          // URL to post
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$loginUsername:$loginPassword"); //login
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
// curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  // make sure we get the header
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); // return into a variable
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'xmlString=' . urlencode($xml_request));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$result = curl_exec( $ch ); // runs the post
curl_close($ch);

}
?>
```

This runs well everywhere else but this particular server where a response is not sent back.  I have also used Firebug to check the request and response headers and both turned out to be empty.

Can anyone help out?

Thanks

James

Comment: What are the differences between the servers? (different OS, PHP version, etc.)

Comment: Hi Jordan,

One of the servers is running PHP 5.3.0 on a Windows Hosted System, the other is running PHP 5.2.11 on a Linux System and the other is running PHP 5.2.9 on a Linux System as well.  All these 3 are working no problem.  The one that refuses to work is running PHP 5.2.5 on a Linux System.  I would have expected to get a response from all 4 but only 3 are giving me a response and the last one is not yet cURL is enabled on it.  One thing thought is that php_info is disabled on the last server.  Would that have an effect?

Comment: James, php_info would not have an effect.  However, what do you mean by "php_info is disabled".  Do you mean you don't have a page that displays php_info?  That is actually a good thing.  You should not leave a server up that someone can publicly access php_info.  It is a security risk.

Have you confirmed that the 4th server can server any web page?  Do you have a test page that you can visit to confirm Apache is running properly on that box?

Comment: Hi Justin, basically the 4th box is already up and running and is currently serving quite a few web pages.  I have been carrying out a few tests myself a today.  On the other 3 boxes, (going by Firebug on Firefox), the content length on the response headers is always greater than 0, indicating that a response is being sent back from the dialling server.  On the 4th box, the content length is always 0. The funny thing is that the same script is being used to collect info from a payment gateway on the 4th box and a response is coming back with no issues.  Is the dialling server at fault!?

Answer (score 1):

Anyway I have discovered the solution to the problem. It seems the dialling server did not accept transfers that started with HEAD request.  I ended up having to modify some portions of my script to make use of the CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST with GET.

At least this time, I am receiving a response.  So that has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to ensure the 4th box is actually setup properly to serve web pages:

From a command line terminal :

```
$ telnet 194.217.1.2 80  (press enter)
```

You should get a response like :

Trying 192.168.245.84...
    Connected to 194.217.1.2.
    Escape character is '^]'.

Type this in:

```
GET /ClickToCall/CallRequest.asmx/Call HTTP/1.1 (press enter)
Host: 194.217.1.2 (press enter twice)
```

You should get a response sort of like this with different HTML info likely:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2009 15:40:13 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.31 (Unix) PHP/4.3.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.3.8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

248

Network Quality Assurance Homepage


Some stuff here